# Android memory leak C# (webView videoView)

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, android-webview

I am creating an android app (C#) that uses webView videoView to view different video streams.

After about 6 minutes the app crashes. I believe it is a memory leak somewhere, but I am having trouble fixing it. I have found a few ways to get around the webView memory leak, but they have all been in java.

Are there any fixes for the memory leak in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a c# Web server streaming data to web clients. 
There is something called a *large object heap* in c#. It puts large objects that should be garbage collected into a heap for later, instead of freeing the memory it uses right away. This improves the performance but in my case and probably in your case as well it never finds the right time to free the memory.

If this is the problem your app is facing you can simply solve it by using this code snippet to tell the garbage collector to free the memory instantly:

```cs
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce; 
GC.Collect();
```

Hope this helps.